# Use environment variable in path and argument in the same command

Tags: powershell

I have created an environment variable `IGNITE_HOME` and then want to use this variable to execute a program in PowerShell as well as passing arguments

If I run the following two commands separately, it works fine:

```
cd $env:IGNITE_HOME/bin
./ignite.bat $env:IGNITE_HOME/examples/config/example-cache.xml
```

but If I try to run it in one line, it does not work:

```
$env:IGNITE_HOME/bin/ignite.bat $env:IGNITE_HOME/examples/config/example-cache.xml
```

I get an error message:

> You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
>   At line:1 char:18

I tried to add double quotes on the arguments, but that did not help either

Comment: Please check if above duplicate link solves your problem.

Comment: Is $env:IGNITE_HOME contain any space ? Can you please provide a value of $env:IGNITE_HOME ?

Comment: Thank you for the link, did not realize if was the same issue. Simply adding an "&" in front solves the problem, double quotes are not required as I don't have any spaces in the path:
& $env:IGNITE_HOME/bin/ignite.bat $env:IGNITE_HOME/examples/config/example-cache.xml